# What is the exact meaning of "lack"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I want to translate a scientific questionnaire to my mother language but unfortunately I am a bit confused about the usage of "lack".

The sentence is that: "My usual diet lacks a variety of food groups"

How should I translate it exactly, as insufficient or absence meaning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot depends on context (which you have not provided).

Comment: the sentence you give does not contain the verb "lack". Your question is rather confusing unless you tell us WHO you think lacks WHAT.

Comment: I'll leave my answer to the title question, as it explains an important point. But you probably want the expression 'I often feel left out [at mealtimes]'; 'a lack of empathy' (and it hardly matters whether this means 0 or 25%) is far too formal.

Comment: I am so sorry. I'd copied wrong sentences. I've edited. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: "lacks" - "does not have".

Answer (score 2):

For the new version with "lack" rather than "lack of".

"My usual diet lacks a variety of food groups" means "My usual diet does not include a variety of food groups" or "My usual diet is missing a variety of food groups".

To look "lack" up in a dictionary, you need to choose the **verb** "lack".

Answer (score 2):

Since this sentence occurs in a questionnaire, it's probably intended as a yes/no question; that is, it sounds like the addressee is supposed to agree or disagree with the statement.

- ***Yes**, my diet lacks a variety of food groups.*
- ***No**, my diet does not lack a variety of food groups.*

And since *lack* means 'not have', a negative predicate, disagreeing with it makes it positive, so that a "No" answer (or checkbox) means

- *My diet has a variety of food groups.*

which in turn means

- *I eat a lot of different kinds of food.*

The key word is *variety*. What the question wants to know is whether the respondent is eating all one kind of food (like rice) instead of lots of different foods. Note that *a variety* is the direct object of *lack*, which means that variety is what's at issue.

Answer (score 0):

(In answer to the original question)

'Lack of', unlike 'lack', is not used as a verb.

Here, it is best to analyse *a lack of* as a single item (lexeme), a compound quantifier, like *a surplus of*, *a lot of*. See for instance [Grammar.ccc.com](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm)

The following quantifiers will work with both count and non-count nouns:

```
 - all of the trees/dancing

 - some trees/dancing

 - most of the trees/dancing

 - enough trees/dancing

 - a lot of trees/dancing

 - lots of trees/dancing

 - plenty of trees/dancing

 - a lack of trees/dancing
```

You should really give the complete sentence. As [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/lack) says, 'a lack of' is inherently ambiguous (there is none vs there is insufficient) and needs context to disambiguate:

> **[a] lack of something**   B1 the fact that something is not available or that there is not enough of it....

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lack) (reformatted) agrees:

> **a lack of something**
>
> If there is a lack of something, there is not enough of it or it does
> not exist at all.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I've shared the complete sentence.

Answer (score -1):

(a) lack of sth means you don't have much of sth.

For example, (a) lack of money/skill/food/funds/good schools/humor/intelligence/confidence